# Good tools for writing (game) manuals and sourcebooks

Tags: technical-writing, tools

As I had asked in another part of Stackexchange (didn't know about this part until some comments there) I'm writing manuals (mostly for computer games, but in addition to this also for tabletop games, pen and paper rpg games) and sourcebooks (world books for tabletop games).

Now I've run into a few troubles there with MS Word, as the text grew fast very cumbersome to organize (I lost oversight quite fast and had to search for parts of the text quite long time and again) and in addition to that I couldn't position text as I needed and also including pictures (screenshots and graphics) was more cumbersome than I would have liked (also using pictures as backgrounds for some of the pages was cumbersome).

So my question is: Are there any good tools out there where I can create such manuals and sourcebooks with?

As a note here: I'll have to print out those manuals/sourcebooks but also want to put them into PDFs.

Edit:
As it was asked in a comment:

- Pictures are very present. Part as charts, part as pieces of art to lighten up the book
- Some pics are taking up a whole page, others take up only part of a page and are in between a section and its text, and others again are background images above which text is printed.
- There are up to 8 different types of texts (titles,...) At some locations the text must be even displayed so that "2 columns" are on the page while on most it's 1 column per page.

Comment: Welcome to Writers!  Can you add a bit to the question about the make-up of such books?  I'm imagining that you have a higher-than-average number of charts, tables, and illustrations, some of which might be large.  Knowing how much of what kinds of content you're trying to accommodate, beyond just the text, will help people give you better answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Put up a bit more infos there

Comment: No prob. If anything still seems to be missing I'll add the info immediately. Especially as there are quite a few tools that are being used by ppl for things like that it can be quite possible that I'm missing to write down some important infos that would be required for recommendations there (especially as every tool has its own pros and cons there).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lauren loves Scrivener I love LaTeX! It lets you code your books, build reusable modules and makes laying out text a breeze.

[Writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/) is an amazing free site that lets you work with LaTeX online, work collaboratively and save your documents as Zips or PDFs.

We use it to write the rulebooks for our tabletop games and RPG systems; we have a template set up with modules that you can elect to include (box contents, aim, setup, etc...) and a default style. Using a style sheet much like CSS we can comment in or out different styles as required, so that we can keep a uniform structure but theme the document on the game in question.

I also use LaTeX for my writing, using a [template](https://www.writelatex.com/templates/fiction-template/mmkvyycphbbc) to split sections into separate modules with a defined plot guide and a handy "things to look for" checklist at the top of each module. I've found splitting the story out into manageable chunks makes it easier to write and stops me from ending up in plot-falls.

Overall I find LaTeX to be not only useful for it's flexability but also for the way that having pre-built, modular documents makes writing a new rulebook a matter of simply changing some options and adding some text. The time it saves us, and the consistency it gives us, is well worth the effort of getting your head round it.

Comment: Last time I used latex was almost 10 years ago. Back then it was lets fromulate it this way: Cumbersome to use. It was almost like writing xml back then with no real editor that I found (so I had to handcode everything). Did that change there?

Comment: @ThomasE. Write Latex makes it a lot easier, giving you a very neat editor with project, code and live preview windows side by side. It also has intelisense and [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure) will tell you pretty much everything you need to know. Once you've coded a template you never have to code again, just dump your text into the modules and run it. My fiction template lets me just write, but if I want thought bolded instead of italicised I just have to change a line of code on a custom macro, instead of finding all the italic text and changing it.

Comment: The other plus is that there is a huge range of macros you can add in, rulebooks are usually best with multiple columns, call-out boxes are very helpful, auto-generated contents pages are a must...

Comment: Multiple columns are a must even for special things like spell lists (saw it af ew times witout and few times with....if there is a huge list of spells or merits,.... it gets quite cumersome to read through if its only 1 column on the page). will take a look at latex later today (currently taking a look at each of the mentioned programs with 1 program per day)

Comment: I thought about pathfinder, wod and old school black eye spell lists there and how rogue trader does it. but same thing there. they are horrible to read without multiple columns and clear indication "new spell here". same for similar situations where many points need to be listed in other types of manuals, ... . or when you list locations on a map for a village for example in a sourcebook or adventurebook you WANT multiple columns there

Comment: looked a bit over latex. how is it to write in it? is it not breaking the flow to use also the tags time and again?

Comment: also do you use the online variant or only the offline variant for sourcebooks,...?

Comment: I see. treid out writelatex on the weekend btw looks quite nice and suited for what I'm trying to accomplish (Scrivener is also good but doesnt have enough layout options which writelatex provides). One question there though as you mentioned backing up to dropbox. Is there an option to do it automatically? (currently I'm backuping by using pdf download,...)

Comment: Sorry @ThomasE. You would need to subscribe for that feature, I forgot about that. Before I subscribed I used the Zip feature. So go to Project, and press Download as Zip, then just put that Zip in your DropBox folder. Honestly it's only one more step than I have to do :)

Comment: ah ok that was it then. what subscription has it included? The pro?

Comment: @ThomasE., it's available from the personal+ version up. We have Pro just becuase the colaboration and change tracking tools are useful but if you're happy to export the zip manually there's not any pressing need to subscribe at all. I only have because I find the features handy, rather than vital.

Comment: I'm working on the books hobbywise (even a computergame). I'm planing on a kickstarter for the game and possible the books though (don't think the company I work for would be happy if I set up a shop aside from using kickstarter^^). Currently wrote 2 chapters for one of the sourcebooks with latex...finding the current documentation to look for is a bit hard for beginners but else it works as I had hoped so far. so for me I'll write the game manual for the computer game and the sourcebooks there.

Comment: @ThomasE. My employers don't mind me running a company on the side as long as it's not in competition. If you're not already I recommend joining the Board and Card Game Designer's Guild, Kickstarter Best Practice and Tabletop RPG Facebook groups; they are a vital source of info and support for taking a game to Kickstarter. [The LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure) is very useful, and if we manage to make our rulebook template more user friendly I'll come back here and send you a link to it. Good luck :)

Comment: tnx will take a look at it. good luck to you too.  I just convinced my company that kickstarter is having no impact on my work schedule so I want to wait a bit until I ask them if also selling the products is a possbility (have a platform already in mind for the computer game and also for the sourcebooks IF my company says yes, else free distribution and getting money for it back in only via kickstarter)

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [Scrivener!](http://literatureandlatte.com/) :)

Scrivener is an incredibly flexible writing program. It allows you to sort your thoughts into multiple documents within a project, see two documents at once, create hyperlinks, drop in photos and audio files, and then export as Word or print to PDF. You can view your documents as notecards on a corkboard with tags and summaries so you can rearrange things easily. You can create "folders" for your documents and view them like a file tree.

If you search the site for Scrivener and check the `scrivener` tag, you'll find more comments here from other users detailing the program's usefulness.

The only other recommendation I could make would be InDesign if the layout is very important, but that's only for the design part, not the organizing and writing part.

Comment: I had taken a look at indesign a while back but I have to admit the renting part is something that really scared me off there (hate it when I have to rent something and can't just buy). 
scrivener looks interesting.

Comment: @ThomasE. Oh I know; I'm refusing to upgrade to Creative Cloud for as long as I can manage. I find renting software to be obnoxious. But if you want a designed page, ID is your best bet.

Comment: same here with renting. I have a complete dislike for tht idea of theirs. 
Just trying out scrivener currently. So in design is better at doing layouts? how so (scrivener looks pretty complete there from what I saw at first glance)?

Comment: btw am I seeing it correct that getting a table of content together requires assistance from anotehr tool (like openoffice or word)?

Comment: @ThomasE. I have only used Scrivener for novels, so I can't speak to a TOC or to laying out pages. It wouldn't occur to me to use Scrivener for those tasks because as a graphic designer, I'd always use InDesign. You'd have to experiment.

Comment: how is indesign ? except the renting (and seemingly no trial) part

Comment: @ThomasE. For layout and publishing, you can't beat it.

Comment: @ThomasE., if you sign up for Adobe Creative Cloud (just the membership and download tool, so no cost) you can then get one month trials of all Adobe software, including InDesign.

Comment: yepp saw it yesterday. first try was......I need to look at the tutorial for that one ^^' (its quite complicated at least for somoene who didn't use it before so will take a glance at the tutorials there)

Comment: @ThomasE. I adore PhotoShop and Lightroom but InDesign and Illustrator threw me completely. There seems to be little continuity between Adobe prograns, so you have to learn from scratch every time :(

Comment: @CLockeWork I'm surprised to see you say that. The Creative Suite is deliberately designed with similar interfaces and shortcuts so that they all *have* continuity.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, I think with more time I'd have probably found that to be the case. I'm not afraid to admit I was scared off by how alien it all seemed. And there are things like shortcuts not being the same. But really I suppose the issue is that each program does something truly unique and it's *that* idea I need to wrap my head around. I certainly want to learn InDesign; it's apparently excellent for making playing cards and I can see a good use for most Adobe stuff for my board game company.

Comment: about scrivener is there a possibility to do a multi column page inside a document that also has 1 column pages?

Comment: @ThomasE. I should be clear: Scrivener is a writing and organizing program; it's not a layout program. You export *from* Scrivener to something else for the final product. Now that you've edited your question, I'm thinking this program may not be what you want to do your final work in.

Comment: no prob at least in the first steps of writing such a book scrivener has uses for sure (that much I have seen so far already of it).  what would you suggest for the final work there?

Comment: @ThomasE. InDesign or Latex depending on your skill set.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum Tnx a lot there. I have upvoted your answer as Scrivener is a very good solution for most things (and also for preliminary work if the design itself is then done with something else) and Indesign is also a good program there. I'm marking the other answer as the solution there though as the positioning parts can be better done with latex / indesign than with scrivener (as there are too many layout things I need), and after trying I find latex more comfortable than indesign to use. tnx alot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the financial resources, the manpower (a team for a synchronized multitasked work environment), the time for self (or paid) training and the will to participate in a much slower than SE community for help, [Adobe's "Technical Communication Suite"](http://www.adobe.com/products/technicalcommunicationsuite.html) is your solution. It's the top notch, state-of-the-art, standards supporting "technical documentation" solution on the market. Just Framemaker itself would convince technical writers to try it for once.

But as I've stated above it has its drawbacks.

If you're a "one man show", you should stick with open source solutions.